# Javascript validation in Form runat=server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm new to .NET and web development in general. I created a form to collect a user's comment and/or a file attachment. Everything works fine but I would like to add client side validation but it fails when I do so. Using Chrome's dev tools I can see the javascript is executed but the first statement fails saying "cannot read property value of undefined". If I remove the runat="server" properties, it works fine but I can no longer access the data from the code behind.

So what options do I have for making the javascript work? Or am I going about saving the data the wrong way?

aspx page:

```
<form id="commentForm" name="commentForm" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return validateCommentForm()">
    <p>Add Comment</p>
    <textarea id="Comment" name="Comment" rows="4" class="with-100" runat="server" />

    <input id="FileAttachment" type="file" runat="server" />

    <input type="submit" id="SaveComment" class="red-button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function validateCommentForm()
{
    var x = document.commentForm.Comment.value;
    var y = document.commentForm.FileAttachment.value;
    if (x == '' && y == '')
    {
        alert("Either a commment or file must be supplied.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

c#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack == true)
            {
                if (Comment.Value.Length > 0)
                {
                    Insert.UserComment(Comment.Value);
                }

                HttpPostedFile UserFileAttachment = Request.Files[0];
                if (UserFileAttachment.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    Insert.FileAttachment(UserFileAttachment);
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery, where you can call the form elements by the name as described in their [API](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Retrieve the value:

```
$("input[name='Comment']").val();
```

To update the value (if needed) from JavaScript:

```
$("input[name='Comment']").val('some Comment');
```

You can also do it by ID (and based on your sample this should work) with the following jQuery:

```
$("#Comment").val();
```

So your final JavaScript would look like:

```
function validateCommentForm()
{
    var x = $("#Comment").val();
    var y = $("#FileAttachment").val();
    if (x == '' && y == '')
    {
        alert("Either a commment or file must be supplied.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I do think there's something odd in accessing the file name from a file input box. See the file selector jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/file-selector/).

Comment: The ClientIDMode property appears to be only a property of ASP.NET controls, not HTML controls. So that solution does not work. Furthermore, I inspected the page at runtime to get the generated IDs, used the existing javascript with the runtime IDs, and it still did not work. Perhaps you could provide an example of the jQuery solution as I am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Ugh, I'm sorry. I just re-checked, and hadn't realized you weren't using the asp:form tag. I'll add the jQuery example now.

Comment: I still had to inspect the element and get the name generated at runtime and edit the jQuery function to use that name, but this solution did work. Thanks.